# Issue Related to Xcode Setting

Tags: xcode

[image]

Hi All of you.

I have problem related to Xcode setting.
Currently i am using xcode Version 4.3.2.

When i will install application in any of the device (iPod,iPhone,Ipad) using cable xcode ask question enter username and password repetitively 2 times.

If i don't enter required information then application not install in deceive.

This problem i have faced after update latest version of Xcode. In previous version when i install app in device this  problem doesn't occur.

So i want to know that if any setting is required in Xcode for solve this problem.

If any one have idea regarding this share it.

Thank You

Regards,
Keyur Bhalodiya

Comment: I want to remove this alert message while install application in device from directly from my computer sing cable.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to remove this message, except you login with root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks system user name and system password. This information is related to security purpose. I don't know about previous version, but in new version, it is more important when we want to install or update any software and some more. I think you know the system username and system password. I can give you information about system username. First click on apple icon-->System Preferences ----> User & Groupes-----> then you can see "Full Name", then name of full name  is system user name and also see Apple Id,  Change password like that. I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this alert message, please login your mac with root. Good luck.

Comment: Hi found solution go to system preferences_>user group